# SQL Server "BAK" bloated file size

Tags: sql-server

I created a backup file of my SQL Server 2012 (not Express edition) database on PC1. The file size of the resulting `.BAK` file was 531 MB.

Then I copied that `.BAK` file to PC2 that had SQL Server 2012 Express edition.
I restored the database from that `.BAK` file.

Then immediately created `.BAK` from that newly created DB on PC2.

Surprisingly, the new `.BAK` file's size was 3 GB.

Can someone please educate me why the newly created `.BAK` file is way too big?

Ozair

Comment: Was the first (non-Express) backup compressed? Also, both of your `backup` statements (exactly as you have issued them) would help to understand the situation.

Comment: I used the GUI to create the backup NOT the sql statements.

Comment: There is a "Script..." button at the top of this window, you can set the options in UI and then see the actual statement that will be executed.

Comment: thanks, its exactly the same (apart from file name or path )

Comment: Run this on both servers to view the default backup compression setting. `EXEC sp_configure 'backup compression default';`

Comment: on non-express it ran with success but on PC2 ( express edition )
it prompted with...

Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 62
The configuration option 'backup compression default' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.